# mglean.plots.plot_animal_tree()でエラー

Tags: anaconda, graphviz

オライリーのPythonではじめる機械学習で勉強中です。
AnacondaでiPythonを使用しています。PCはWindows10.

決定木のところの `mglearn.plots.plot_animal_tree()` でエラーが発生しました。
graphvizをインストールしろとのことだったので、pipでインストールし、環境変数にPathも通しましたが、下記エラーで動きません。

```
FileNotFoundError:[WinError2]指定されたファイルが見つかりません。
ExcutableNotFoud: failed to excute ['dot','-Tpng','-O','tmp'], make sure the Graphviz executable are on your systems' PATH
```

condaでgraphvizをインストールしなければいけないのかと思い、`conda install graphviz` を実行しましたが、

```
Note: you may need to restart the karnel to use update packages
```

となり、インストールできません。

どうすれば、解決するでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 通したPath下にdot.exeはありますか？

Comment: Path下にdot.exeはなく、dot.pyはあります。PCを再起動したところ、mglean.plots.plot_animal_tree()でグラフが表示されました。しかし、graphviz.Source(dot_graph)では、何も表示されません。

Comment: graphvizをWin10でインストールすると、どこかにdot.exeが配置されます。実処理はこのdot.exeが行うため、dot.exeが配置されたフォルダをPathに追加する必要があります。

Comment: dot.exeが配置されたフォルダにPathを修正しました。PC再起動し、graphviz.Source(dot_graph)を試しましたが、何も表示されません。

Comment: ExcutableNotFoud: failed to excute ['dot','-Tpng','-O','tmp'], make sure the Graphviz executable are on your systems' PATHのエラーがまだ出るということですか？

Comment: エラーは出なくなりました。mglean.plots.plot_animal_tree()では決定木の描画はできました。しかし、scikit-learnで作られたdot形式のファイルをgraphvizで可視化しようとしていますが、graphviz.Source(dot_graph)で何も表示されません。

Comment: graphviz.Source(dot_graph)の件は、改めて質問した方がよいと思います。どんなコードを実行したのか、どんなモジュールをインストールしたのかを明示すると回答が得られやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

**回答**
　`mglean.plots.plot_animal_tree()`は以下の**手順**で画像が表示されるはずです。

- 1)を実行しないと次のエラーが発生します。
- 5)を実行しないと画像が表示されません、エラーも出ません。
  ここでいうgraphvizは、1)のgraphviz(dot)をPythonから使うためのものです。
- 確認していませんが、3)の`Channels`とコードを実行するときの`Channels`は同じでないと駄目な気がします。

```
ExcutableNotFoud: failed to excute ['dot','-Tpng','-O','tmp'], make sure the Graphviz executable are on your systems' PATH
```

**手順**
　1)Win10にてgraphvizをインストール
　　`dot.exe`が配置されたパスを環境変数`Path`に追加
　2)Win10にて`Anaconda Navigator`を起動
　3)ANACONDA NAVIGATORにて`CMD.exe Prompt`を起動
　4)CMDにて`mglearn`をインストール

```
pip install mglearn
```

5)CMDにて`graphviz`をインストール

```
pip install graphviz
```

**確認したコード**

```
import mglearn
mglearn.plots.plot_animal_tree()
```

**結果**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]